# React Native App - Connect device for debugging to running Metro network

Tags: react-native, adb

I use physical Android device to debug my React Native project. Each time I disconnect device USB from computer, to reconnect to Metro after connecting device to computer again for debugging, I will have to run: `yarn android` which sometimes takes forever to finish building and start intent to connect to Metro network.

Ques: Is there a way to connect my device port to Metro network by simply running `yarn start` and `adb -s 098743733L146081 shell` (where 098743733L146081 is my device id for connecting to adb) without having to always build afresh?